# Getting info from another table with Propel?

Tags: symfony, propel

I have a users table, which has a foreign key with another table called town,

Now I'm trying to get all users including the name of the town they belong to,

```
$users = UserQuery::create()
 ->select(array('fos_user.id, fos_user.username, fos_user.email, town.name'))
 ->joinWith('Town')
 ->find();
```

I tried this but it threw up a SELECT execution error for some reason. If someone could point me into the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add the error's text into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by specifically specifying what table I wanted to join with, then pass a select to get the fields I want.

```
$users = UserQuery::create()
        ->joinWith('Town')
        ->select(array('id','username', 'email', 'Town.name'))
        ->find()
        ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for is `useXXXXQuery()` though I don't think this is a proper usage of it.

If your schema is correct you can simply call `$user->getTown()->getName()` or you can make a method on the user model `getTownName()` that calls the above code.

A situation where you would want to use the `useXXXXQuery()` is where you were creating conditions for a user regarding it's relationship in a foreign table:

```
$users = UserQuery::create()
                  ->filterByAge(13,Criteria::GREATER_THAN)
                  ->filterByStatus('active')
                    ->useTownQuery()
                    ->filterByName('Your Town')
                    ->endUse()
                  ->find();
```

Now this is doing it with objects. If you are dealing with massive amounts of data this may not be a good idea as it would take a significant amount of memory. I would rather loop through objects than arrays. Makes it cleaner and easier.